# Bootstrap dropdown menu 3 levels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have a left dropdown menu with bootstrap, I need to deploy the third level (Submenu 1, 2, 3, 4)
on the right side of the menu, in this way:

```
Services

     Submenus      Submenu1
                   Submenu2
                   Submenu3
                   Submenu4
```

I have achieved dropdown vertically below submenus

```
Services

     Submenus     
     Submenu1
     Submenu2
     Submenu3
     Submenu4
```

Here is the menu [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/f6Ew1A7pam)

Please help me! :)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
.nav-side-menu { overflow:visible }
.nav-side-menu ul ul ul { position:fixed; left:300px; top:0; }
```